# Expressão para remover links de URL do twitter tweet

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma expressão para remover links que estejam presentes em um arquivo .CSV na linguagem Python.

Ex de texto:

> joao foi no mercado http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/genera  quero que esse texto apareça

Com isso quero que a saída seja:

> joao foi no mercado quero que esse texto apareça

Tenho esse código. Ele remove o link mas também o texto que vem depois

```
URLless_string = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', str(linha))
print(str(URLless_string))
```

Comment: Por quê o [código](http://ideone.com/VAnRo2) foi removido da pergunta? Ele aparentemente funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça isto:

```
import re

linha = raw_input("Entre com o tweet: ")
URLless_string = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", str(linha))
print(str(URLless_string))
```

- `http` casa com caracteres literais
- `\S+` casa com todos os caracteres não em branco (até o final da url)
- substitui com a string vazia

Exemplo online [aqui](https://repl.it/JCTf/2).

Comment: E se a URL não possuir o esquema HTTP(S)? Por exemplo, FTP.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que o OP poderia especificar para nós na pergunta dele se haverá links com início diferente de `http`

Comment: Só haverá inicio com http

Comment: @thiagoxavier então o código que forneci funciona

Comment: Funcionou em partes !Ele faz praticamente a mesma coisa desse que tem na minha pergunta.Remove a URL mas também remove o texto que vem depois.Acho q o codigo pra analisar essa sentença tem de levar em consideração o espaço em branco e saber que apos esse espaço é um texto normal que nao deve ser removido

Comment: @thiagoxavier atualizei a resposta

Comment: Funcionou !!!Obrigado